# What are the other uses of __new__ method in python?

Tags: python, oop, new-operator, magic-methods

Here I have defined immutable class str.
In  **new** method I am changing the values of instances such as "hello" to uppercase. Why should we do it using **new** when we can define upper in **init** ?

```
class Upperstr(str):
    def __new__(cls,value=""):
        print(cls)
        print(value)
        return str.__new__(cls,value.upper())

    # def __init__(self,m1):
    #     self.m1 = m1.upper()
    
u = Upperstr("hello")
print(u)
```

New is used to create class instances.
What are the other uses of **new** method?

Comment: "Why should we do it using new when we can define upper in init ?" Have you actually tried that? Note that the commented out ``__init__`` does something entirely different than the ``__new__`` – it sets an attribute on the string, not the value of the string.

Comment: Only use is it is hidden func for creating an instance. Runs before `def __init__`.

Answer (score 8):

> New is used to create class instances. What are the other uses of **new**
> method?

You can use `__new__` to implement singleton pattern (where pattern must be understand as thing described in *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software*), take look at example provided by [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-pattern-in-python-a-complete-guide/) of **Classic Singleton**

```
class SingletonClass(object):
  def __new__(cls):
    if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
      cls.instance = super(SingletonClass, cls).__new__(cls)
    return cls.instance
   
singleton = SingletonClass()
new_singleton = SingletonClass()
 
print(singleton is new_singleton)
 
singleton.singl_variable = "Singleton Variable"
print(new_singleton.singl_variable)
```

Comment: Classes that lie about making objects are terrible. If you want a singleton, write a class and just instantiate it once: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202204/singleton_is_a_bad_idea.html

Answer (score 1):

Your question was something like,

> Under what conditions is `__new__` better to use than `__init__` in Python?

---

Suppose that we have a very simple class named `Point`

```python
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x:float, y:float):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
```

We instantiate the `Point` class as follows:

```python
# construct and initialize paula the point
paula = Point(10.2, 7.4)
```

In order to help explain what `__new__` does, I will write a classmethod named `make_point` which has almost the same behavior as `paula = = Point(10.2, 7.4)`.

```python
class Point():
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("__new__(" + ", ".join(str(x) for x in [cls, *args]) + ")")
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        return obj

    def __init__(self, y:float, y:float):
        args = (y, y)
        print("__init__(" + ", ".join(str(x) for x in [self, *args]) + ")")
        self._y = y
        self._y = y

    @classmethod
    def make_point(cls, *args):
        new_instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
        if isinstance(new_instance, cls):
            cls.__init__(new_instance, *args)
        return new_instance
```

Now we can instantiate the `Point` class as follows:

```python
peter = Point.make_point(59.87, 5.91)
```

The `__init__` method is unable to replace the `self` parameter with something new and different.

For example, people sometimes want want to put a wrapper around the `self` parameter. You might want something like this:

```python
import functools
import sys

class decorator:

    def __new__(cls, kallable):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        instance = functools.update_wrapper(instance, kallable)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, kallable):
        self._kallable = kallable
        self._file     = sys.stdout

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("__init__(" + ", ".join(str(x) for x in [self, *args]) + ")", file=self._file)
        return self._kallable(*args, **kwargs)

@decorator
def pow(base:float, exp:int):
    """
         +------------------------------------------+
         |                EXAMPLES                  |
         +------------------------------------------+
         | BASE | EXPONENT |       OUTPUT           |
         +------+----------+------------------------+
         |    2 |        5 | 2^5      |          32 |
         |  2.5 |        7 | 2.5^7    | 610.3515625 |
         |   10 |        3 | 10^3     |        1000 |
         |  0.1 |        5 | 0.1^5    |     0.00001 |
         |    7 |        0 | 7^0      |           1 |
         +------+----------+----------+-------------+
    """
    base = float(base)
    # convert `exp` to string to avoid flooring, or truncating, floats
    exp  = int(str(exp))
    if exp > 0:
        return base * pow(base, exp-1)
    else: # exp == 2
        return 1

result1 = pow(2, 5)
result2 = pow(8.1, 0)
print("pow(2, 5) == "  , result1)
print("pow(8.1, 0) == ", result2)

print("What is the documentation string? The doc-string is... ", pow.__doc__)
```

It will not help to use `functools.update_wrapper` inside of `__init__`. If you try to write the following...

```python
class f:
    def __init__(self, inner):
        # Here, the wrapper callable (function o functor) is named `self`
        self = functools.update_wrapper(self, inner)
```

... then `self = foo(self)` will be ignored.

In python, you are not allowed to replace the parameter named `self` with a different `self`

The `__new__` method is nice because it allows us to replace `self` with a wrapper around `self`

```python
import functools

class decorator:

    def __new__(cls, wrapped):
        assert(callable(wrapped))
        wrapper = super().__new__(cls)
        wrapper = functools.update_wrapper(wrapper, wrapped)
        wrapper._kallable = kallable  
        return wrapper

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        return self._kallable(*args, **kwargs)
```

Without using `functools.update_wrapper` inside of `__new__` the doc-string inside of the original callable will be wiped-out, ignored, not inherited, and/or shadowed.

Answer (score -2):

**new** is basically a standard Python method that is invoked before **init** when a class instance is created. For further information, see the python **new** manual:  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__

There is not other direct usage of it.

Regarding the difference between Init/New: The constructor function in python is called **new** and **init** is the initializer function. According to the Python documentation, **new** is used to control the creation of a new instance, whereas **init** is used to handle its initialization.